# How to know if goroutine still exist?

Tags: go, goroutine

Is there a comparable function like java `Thread.isAlive()` for goroutine?

I am trying to spawn some goroutine that is meant to be long living threads, but I am afraid that goroutine can die mid process, is there a check that I can do in my main thread to see if goroutine is alive?

Comment: Explanation for downvote would be much appreciated, as it allow me to improve or clarify the problem :)

Comment: "I am afraid that goroutine can die mid process." Why? Goroutines don't just randomly stop. They end if they hit a return statement, or the end of the function body, or if a panic occurs (which usually crashes the program anyway).

Comment: "I am afraid that goroutine can die mid process" definitely needs more explanation. There is normally no reason to have such a fear.

Comment: if you're concerned about a panic (although one should rarely panic in go) - one can implement a panic handler and recover (http.Handler's do this i.e. they don't want a bad http request handler bringing down an entire web-server). But repeating the other comments here, go-routines do not die, they merely complete.

Answer (score 13):

The best way is not to know if it's till alive but to know when it dies so you can restart it.

You can do that by setting a `defer` with a `recover` on your goroutine which would write to a channel signaling the death of the goroutine. Then on the main goroutine, you read from that channel, and whenever something is read, you restart a goroutine. You could identify wich goroutine failed by returning a struct containing the goroutine id and the error.

Example:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// number of desired workers
const nWorkers = 10

func main() {
        // make a buffered channel with the space for my 10 workers
        workerChan := make(chan *worker, nWorkers)

        for i := 0; i < nWorkers; i++ {
                i := i
                wk := &worker{id: i}
                go wk.work(workerChan)
        }

        // read the channel, it will block until something is written, then a new
        // goroutine will start
        for wk := range workerChan {
                // log the error
                fmt.Printf("Worker %d stopped with err: %s", wk.id, wk.err)
                // reset err
                wk.err = nil
                // a goroutine has ended, restart it
                go wk.work(workerChan)
        }
}

type worker struct {
        id  int
        err error
}

func (wk *worker) work(workerChan chan<- *worker) (err error) {
        // make my goroutine signal its death, wether it's a panic or a return
        defer func() {
                if r := recover(); r != nil {
                        if err, ok := r.(error); ok {
                                wk.err = err
                        } else {
                                wk.err = fmt.Errorf("Panic happened with %v", r)
                        }
                } else {
                        wk.err = err
                }
                workerChan <- wk
        }()

        // do something
        // ...

        return err
}
```

Comment: Pretty nice template :+1:
I made a gist out of it https://gist.github.com/fentas/04c1e59f6cde0defaa16d8f8ecc78f89 after some modifications.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a comparable function like java Thread.isAlive() for goroutine?

No. You have to redesign your solution. Goroutines have no identity and cannot be accessed in any way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement it yourself, to check if specific goroutine is alive, [e.g.](https://go.dev/play/p/5O6GaaS_o3E):

```
func routine(id int) {
    atomic.StoreInt32(&alive[id], 1)       // set alive
    defer wg.Done()                        // for main sync
    defer atomic.StoreInt32(&alive[id], 0) // gone
    d := rand.Intn(200)
    defer func() { fmt.Println("gone:", id, "after", time.Since(t0), "d =", d) }() // show

    time.Sleep(time.Duration(d) * time.Millisecond) // job
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go routine(i)
    }

    id := rand.Intn(max)

    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(200)) * time.Millisecond)

    fmt.Println(id, "is alive:", atomic.LoadInt32(&alive[id]) == 1, "after", time.Since(t0))

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(len(alive)) // 10
}

const max = 10

var (
    wg    sync.WaitGroup
    alive = make([]int32, max)
    t0    = time.Now()
)
```

Output:

```
gone: 5 after 25ms d = 25
gone: 4 after 47ms d = 47
gone: 0 after 56ms d = 56
gone: 9 after 59ms d = 59
gone: 7 after 81ms d = 81
1 is alive: true after 87ms
gone: 3 after 94ms d = 94
gone: 2 after 100ms d = 100
gone: 6 after 111ms d = 111
gone: 8 after 118ms d = 118
gone: 1 after 140ms d = 140
10
```